# Why are two such similar movies being made at the same time?

Tags: production, book-adaptation, the-jungle-book-2016, mowgli-legend-of-the-jungle

Everybody perhaps knows of Jon Favreau's movie [The Jungle Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jungle_Book_(2016_film)) which is going to be released in 2016. But quite recently I learned (and to my utter surprise) that another Jungle book movie is coming in 2017 and it's called [Jungle Book: Origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungle_Book:_Origins).

Now, this movie has big names too with Christian Bale as Baghera, Benedict Cumberbatch as Sher Khan, Cate Blanchett as Kaa and a young Indian boy in the live action role as Mowgli.

How often does this happen, with two big productions with big cast making a movie on the same subject? I want to ask why this is happening and if there are any really significant differences between the two (apart from the cast, of course).

Comment: BTW if you're after the *how*, both studios have the rights because *The Jungle Book* is in the public domain.

Comment: Here's an article from two days ago: https://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/features/twin-films-same-subject-figure-character-first-man-the-first-white-house-down-olympus-has-fallen-a8616881.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes, people have the same idea at the same time.  A few notable times this has happened:

- [*Tombstone* and *Wyatt Earp*](https://uproxx.com/filmdrunk/heres-why-tombstone-and-wyatt-earp-were-released-six-months-apart-twenty-years-ago/)
- *Antz* and *A Bugs Life*
- *Mission To Mars* and *Red Planet*
- *The Abyss* and *Deep Star Six* and *Leviathan*
- *1492: Conquest of Paradise* and *Christopher Columbus: The Discovery*
- *Mirror Mirror* and *Snow White and the Huntsman*
- *Armageddon* and *Deep Impact*
- *Capote* and *Infamous*
- *Dante's Peak* and *Volcano*
- *Olympus Has Fallen* and *White House Down*
- *Gordy* and *Babe*
- *Saving Private Ryan* and *The Thin Red Line*
- *No Strings Attached* and *Friends With Benefits*

In all these cases, the movies were released within a few months of each other.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back up that it was different people coming up with the same idea? I always thought (and the source you've provided supports) that it was the same idea that diverges into two separate films that have a different story focus.

Comment: I'd have to research them, or someone else could and just edit my answer.  I was just going from the top of my head, and I had read that Wiki page about Tombstone/Earp a year or so ago when I was wondering why both movies were released around the same time so I knew where to grab that reference.  I'm sure there's even more of them (didn't edTV and The Truman Show come out around the same time too?), but I do have a full-time job.  ;o)

Comment: @Mike.C.Ford [It happens for many reasons, really.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_films)

Comment: There were two Hercules movies a couple of years ago, one starring Dwayne Johnson and one starring somebody who wasn't Dwayne Johnson.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I think if The Jungle Book and The Legend of Tarzan (also releasing in 2016) were to be discussed in the same context as this question, then this list would be apt.

Comment: @Ankit - Well, considering they have nothing in common but the basis of the story, it's very much in line with Wyatt Earp/Tombstone, the two Columbus movies and the two Snow White movies.  The two Jungle Book movies have no common thread (cast, producers, etc...) except that they're both based on the same story.

Comment: I read about Tombstone and Wyatt Earp. That was really relevant. But do we have any story in this case, I mean that's what my question is. We know how Tombstone and Wyatt Earp got made together, but what about this case here

Comment: From my various readings (which I don't have time to link to here, or I'd make this a proper answer), my impression is that a lot of these answers, and the Wiki page, miss the psychology of the movie biz. There's a weird duality between competitiveness ("we'll make an EVEN BETTER gritty reboot of Snow White") and fear ("the public wants movies about volcanoes---we'd better make a movie about volcanoes!"). You can find supporting anecdotes in books about the Golden Age of Hollywood. (I'll add some links later if I have a chance.)

Comment: Don't forget *Dark City*, *The Matrix*, *The Thirteenth Floor*, and *eXistenZ*.

Comment: In the case of Antz and A Bug's Life, it actually is not just two people with the same idea. John Lasseter told Jeff Katzenberg about the idea for A Bug's Life while they both worked at Pixar. Katzenberg later left Disney when he didn't receive the promotion he wanted and founded Dreamworks and copied the idea. Katzenberg denied that he copied the idea, but this is clearly not true.

Comment: If we're listing films like this in the comments - lets add Megamind and Despicable Me.

Comment: *The China Syndrome* and *ABC News* both were about nuclear reactor loss of coolant accidents, both due to remote indications not displaying actual conditions.

Answer (score 10):

This is a case of what is known as "Twin Films". I'm not sure who coined the phrase exactly but there is a Wikipedia article which details some of the reasons that twin films are made and there is also a pretty comprehensive list of examples.

Some possible reasons that twin films occur as mentioned in the article are:

1. Two or more production companies investing in similar scripts around the same time
2. Industrial espionage
3. The movement of staff between studios
4. The same screenplays are sent to several film studios before being accepted
5. Films dealing with topical issues, such as volcanic eruptions, reality television, terrorist attacks or significant anniversaries, resulting in multiple discovery of the concept

> #### [Twin Films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_films)
>
> *Twin films are films with the same, or very similar, plot produced or released at the same time by two different film studios.* The phenomenon can result from two or more production companies investing in similar scripts around the same time, resulting in a race to distribute the films to audiences. Some attribute twin films to industrial espionage, the movement of staff between studios, or that the same screenplays are sent to several film studios before being accepted. Another possible explanation is if the films deal with topical issues, such as volcanic eruptions, reality television, terrorist attacks or significant anniversaries, resulting in multiple discovery of the concept.
>
> Screenwriter Terry Rossio notes that there are always multiple film projects with similar subjects being developed in multiple studios while usually only one of them makes it into production in a given period of time, and therefore twin films are better regarded as exceptions. In one case, for the 1974 film The Towering Inferno, the fear of having competing action thrillers, both set in a burning skyscraper, convinced two Hollywood studios to merge their productions into one (all-star) film.