# Why do low production studios intentionally release similar films shortly after a big banner?

Tags: production

Two movies with almost the same name and plot are released together.

[**Overlord (2018)**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4530422/) was released on 9 November 2018 in the USA and produced by J.J. Abrams who is a well-known director and producer in Hollywood. A second movie is [**Nazi Overlord (2018)**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8760550/), released on 13 November 2018 in the USA and produced by not so well known people.

A similar situation was with [**Operation Dunkirk (2017)**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6836772/) and [**Dunkirk (2017)**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5013056/).

From the synopsis, both movies have almost the same plot and name.

This [related question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46797/why-are-two-such-similar-movies-being-made-at-the-same-time) is about *twin films* whereas I am asking about *low production* studios making intentional releases shortly after the release by a big banner.

What's the point of releasing such similar movies at the same time?

Comment: Are you talking about these two movies *specifically*? Or [Twin films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_films) in general?

Comment: @BruceWayne for that we already have: [Two magician films released nearly the same time.. any connection?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88785/two-magician-films-released-nearly-the-same-time-any-connection) and [Why are two such similar movies being made at the same time?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46797/why-are-two-such-similar-movies-being-made-at-the-same-time). But this one seems worth new question to em as it's more of mockbuster not twin film

Comment: AFAICT, "twin films" are more or less coincidental (bad blood between studios notwithstanding), while this question seems to be asking about *deliberate* copies. So I would not call it a duplicate question.

Comment: In the Dunkirk case, it could be attributed to an almost-anniversary of the actual event.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: Check the list of mockbusters by [The Asylum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Asylum).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

To capitalize on the success of its predecessor. Even [IMDb said the same](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8760550/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv) in their trivia section:

> The movie is being released on November 13th, 2018 to capitalize on the release of 'Overlord', which premieres on November the 9th.

The same applied to *Operation Dunkirk (2017)* too. And this is not a new thing, there is a category of such movies called [Mockbuster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockbuster).

> A mockbuster is a movie created with the intention of exploiting the publicity of another major motion picture with a similar title and/or subject. Mockbusters are often made with a low budget and quick production to maximize profit.

Comment: [The Asylum](http://newsite.theasylum.cc/index.php/titles/) is notorious for this practice. Their other Mockbusters include Alien Predator, Atlantic Rim, Transmorphers, Triassic World, End of the World, Avengers Grimm Time Wars, Tomb Invader, Troy: The Odyssey, Geo-Disaster, CarGo, The Fast and the Fierce, Independents' Day, Jack the Giant Killer, Abraham Lincoln vs Zombies, etc...

Comment: The popular viewpoint is that the Mockbuster capitalises on DVD sales from confused consumers seeing it in the bargain bin ("oh look, that movie I'd vaguely heard of is out already"). It's conceivable that the move to streaming might kill this.

Comment: In Japan, they put these fake movies right alongside the regular ones in DVD rental stores (these still exist here). I'm sure many people must have been tricked into renting these.

Comment: Supposedly they actually have their own independent business model now - i.e. some people collect them ;)

Comment: @Schwern: Good information. I would add that myself to answer but since its you brought it to light please add it to answer.

Comment: @Rahul Done. Also note that [MST3K will be doing Atlantic Rim as part of The Gauntlet this Thursday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdBCpnqFNew). Best way to enjoy these monstrosities.

Comment: OMG.  I genuinely had no idea that MST3K was even still around.  I adored that show back in the late 80s to early 90s.  I just might have to watch this marathon...

Comment: I remember renting Robin Hood in the nineties as a kid, thinking it would be the same movie as in the theatres. They fooled me out of my weekly allowance.

Answer (score 21):

This is a film by [The Asylum](http://newsite.theasylum.cc/index.php/titles/). You might know them as the people behind Sharknado and Megashark vs Giant Octopus. As [@ankit explained](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/93989/13258) Nazi Overlord is a Mockbuster, a cheaply made copycat rushed to market to capitalize on the popularity and advertising of a big budget film.

Some people get tricked into buying them. Some people watch them deliberately for the joy of bad movies. [MST3K: The Gauntlet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdBCpnqFNew) will be featuring one of their mockbusters, [Atlantic Rim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVpQmZmKNmo). Watch for the submarine. There's always a submarine.

[Their other mockbusters include](http://newsite.theasylum.cc/index.php/titles/)...

- Alien Predator (The Predator)
- Atlantic Rim (Pacific Rim)
- Transmorphers (Transformers)
- Triassic World (Jurassic World)
- Avengers Grimm Time Wars (The Avengers)
- Tomb Invader (Tomb Raider)
- Troy: The Odyssey (Troy)
- Geo-Disaster (Geostorm)
- CarGo (Cars)
- The Fast and the Fierce (The Fast and the Furious)
- Independents' Day (Independence Day)
- Jack the Giant Killer (Jack the Giant Slayer)
- Abraham Lincoln vs Zombies (Abraham Lincoln Vampire Hunter)
- War of the Worlds (War of the Worlds)
- Sinister Squad (Suicide Squad)
- Snakes on a Train (Snakes on a Plane)
- I Am Omega (I Am Legend)
- 2012: Doomsday (2012)
- 2012: Supernova (2012)
- AvH: Alien vs Hunter (AvP: Alien vs Predator)
- Sunday School Musical (High School Musical)
- The 18-Year-Old Virgin (The 40-Year-Old Virgin)
- The Day The Earth Stopped (The Day The Earth Stood Still)
- The Terminators (Terminator)
- Paranormal Entity (Paranormal Activity)
- Titanic 2 (That's it, I'm leaving)

Comment: "The 18 Year-old Virgin" ... but ... that ... like ... defeats the whole point of the joke ... <head explodes>

Comment: I can't believe *Snakes on a Train* wasn't the official sequel. They missed a great franchising opportunity. I look forward to the prequel, set in the 1800s, *Snakes on a Plain*.

Comment: @BruceWayne "I will not abide these God forsaken snakes on this God forsaken plain!"