# How commercially successful, in general are Mockbuster movies?

Tags: cinema-history

How commercially successful, in general are Mockbuster movies?

[In a previous answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93987/two-movies-with-same-plot-and-name-release-together-whats-the-point), they state that Mockbuster movies are made cheaply to turn a quick profit. Quoting from that answer and [Wikipedia:Mockbuster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockbuster) :

> Mockbusters are often made with a low budget and quick production to
>   maximize profit.

There must be a good commercial motive to make and market these movies; however, it is difficult to find any clear business analysis of this "genre".

Edit:

A question in the comments by Luciano:

> It seems some mockbusters are more successful than others, so how to
>   get a "General" overview of the genre? How do you determine a
>   commercial success in this case? Based on its own costs or compared to
>   the original being copied?

I naively would say something like "profit is revenue minus expenses" but after looking at the [Hollywood Accounting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_accounting) wikipedia page, it seems like that won't work at all. Perhaps "gross revenue minus productions costs" will work? I am open to suggestions though, about how to count this.

Comment: My first instinct is to mark this as off topic due to it being [trivia](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/whats-trivia-and-where-do-we-draw-the-line/55#55)... Is there anything else to this question that might make it less trivial?

Comment: I think this is about as trivial as "Who's the oldest person to play a teenager in a popular movie?" That was a popular question!

Comment: Ok, I have completely reformulated the question. Is this any better? If not, what else can I add? I already have 4 votes, so there is some merit in the topic I think.

Comment: I think this will depend on the quality of the movie itself. It seems some mockbusters are more successful than others, so how to get a "General" overview of the genre? How do you determine a commercial success in this case? Based on its own costs or compared to the original being copied?

Comment: I don't understand why this got reopenend. Even with the limited scope, it still involves data that is likely not accessible or unreliable: both gross revenue and production costs. Mockbusters earn money through DVD sales and broadcast rights. You can measure their success by looking at the companies producing them: if they're still in business, their product is making a profit. Other than that, it's anyone's guess.

Comment: Since when does the difficulty of acquiring data make questions invalid? I'm afraid not *everything* is answerable by a single Wikipedia quote. Also, the reason it was closed for doesn't *remotely* apply to the question in its revised form anymore and it got fit into a shape that seems just about tight *enough* to deserve a chance.

Comment: What is meant by "in general?" In general, movies are commercially successful, else there would be no movie industry. "In general" this genre of movie is probably of more limited success, as they are rarely made today.

Comment: @theMayer See the word "maximize" in the wikipedia quote? I'm looking for numbers on how profitable this "maximize" would be.

Comment: @axsvl77 - another general term. There is no profit ceiling for movies, but low budget movies tend to have low box office grosses, translating to low returns. For all movies, it's an ROI function. I have an issue with the question because it seems to show a general lack of understanding on how businesses operate, and I'm looking to see if we can't narrow down the focus to something that is answerable.

Comment: I think any answer to this question would have to depend on (a) the particular movie, (b) the particular studio, (c) the domestic vs. international gross, and (d) the year.

Answer (score 3):

It may be impossible to answer this question for the mockbuster industry as a whole from outside the industry, without a reliable way to count profits made outside a box office. However, one mockbuster-heavy studio, The Asylum, has released some numbers. According to [GQ](https://www.gq.com/story/sharknado-atlantic-rim-pacific-rim-asylum-movie-spoof), their films normally cost ~500,000 dollars to make and turn 125,000 to 250,000 in profit. In the most literal sense, turning any profit is commercial success. However, their return on investment isn't great compared to A-list studio pictures that can bring in more than double their budgets.